# Making the scrollView move certain size in x axis using React Native?

Tags: react-native

I have scrollView with pagingEnabled to scroll through images, which works fine, but it scrolls through half of the second image, see the animated gif attached

https://media.giphy.com/media/xUA7b6pv9MNdp0R97O/giphy.gif

**Code:**

```
<ScrollView 
     style={{flex:1}}
     horizontal
     ref={(scrollView) => { this.scrollView = scrollView }}
     automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
     directionalLockEnabled
     alwaysBounceVertical={false}
     pagingEnabled
     scrollsToTop={false}>


    <Image style={styles.destination} source={require("../images/favdest1.jpg")} />
    <Image style={styles.destination} source={require("../images/favdest1.jpg")} />
    <Image style={styles.destination} source={require("../images/favdest1.jpg")} />


</ScrollView>
```

How can i make the scrollView snap to a certain width or a children view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React Native `ScrollView` has no way to directly snap to a given width; However, you can implement this by using the following props:

**onScrollEndDrag**: Function, gets called as soon as the user lifts the finger off the screen after scrolling

**onMomentumScrollEnd**: Function, gets called as soon as the ScrollView stops sliding due to simulated momentum after the user lifts their finger off the screen.

You can use these methods to figure out whether the user has stopped scrolling and call `scrollTo` on the `ScrollView` in order to make the view "snap" to the width you want.

However, this is quite non-trivial, and the functionality you want already exists as the [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel) component. :)